# Take variables from Table View Controller to Custom Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Is there anyway to take variables from Table View Controller to Custom Cell? I have Custom cell to configure the cell in TVC cellForRowAtIndexPath, but i haven't figured out how to take variables in TVC and use it in Custom Cell. Thank you.
Here's the example:
I have a variable in my SearchResultTVC which is var cities = City. in SearchResultTVC cellForRowAtIndexPath i'm using customCell which need to take cities variable and use it in its own class. Can we do that? Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please consider posting some code and be more specific about your problem.

Comment: According to the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern the controller (TVC) is supposed to change data in the model (data source) and update the view (cell)

Comment: Is everything you want to do in the same ViewController? Please add some code...

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting it correctly then you want to access control (label , button etc ) from custom cell outside the tableview delegate so best way to access it to store **ROW** (indexpath.row) and **section** (indexpath.section) and then wherever you want you can access it .

Here this way :

let cell = UITableViewCell() by passing Indexpath . 
**Note - Chk UITableviewCell() method different format and use one which accepting indexpath .

Comment: I want to take variables from Table View Controller and use it in Custom Cell where I'm initialize it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. so var cities = [City]() in TableViewController which will be used in Custom Cell.

Comment: basically taking one variable from class, and use it in another class.

Comment: you mean you want to fetch outlet from custom cell rit !

Comment: i want to use variables from one class to another class i guess.